# sum formula in crystal reports based on conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I create a formula "class_section": {Monthlyfeemaster.Class} & {Monthlyfeemaster.Section}

then create a formula

sum_tuition_class_section: sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee}, {@class_section})

it is giving an error:" there must be group that matches this field"

Answer (score 0):

That's because it thinks you're summing all tuition fees in one class_section. class_section is not one of your groups. Do

```
sum({@class_section}, {Monthlyfeemaster.GroupFieldName})
```

This will add up all class_sections per group.

Class and section sound like strings though. Do you mean to sum all tuition fees per class_section. If so, your code is right but you have to create a class_section group somewhere on your report.

Comment: How to create a class_section group in reports

Comment: look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091302/crystal-reports-group-by